# How to know which package is launching?

Tags: android

I have downloaded 'Application Protection' application from market.
It allows me to protect to open any application with password.

i.e. I have protected 'ConnectionLost' Application with Application Protection.

Now when I open 'ConnectionLost' App. I found below log in Logcat.

Line 1-**Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.connectionlost/.ConnectionLost } from pid 5746**

Line 2-**Starting: Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.ruimaninfo.approtect/.ui.ScreenLocker } from pid 5494**

It means first my application launch and after 'applicaton protection' launch it's own activity.

So my question is

**How 'Application protection(Downlaode from market)' know that which package is launched?
and As programmer how can we know the same thing?**

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out which package is launching by Activity Manager

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
String ClassName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getClassName();

You can make one background service which has a timer task of 100 seconds 
and put this code in timertask which prints log at every 100 seconds that which package is launching
```