# How to know which activity is presently opened?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am new to android.

I am developing one app.

Based on that when my application will start,a back ground service will start.

And it run background and notifi the user,when user starts new activity.

For example user opens the camera,contacts..through the background service i want to get 
every time which activity is opened.

If any one has the solution,please help me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756938/how-to-know-activity-has-been-finished

Comment: @kiran did you got the card swiper project?

Comment: Take a llok at following thread:

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8876885/how-to-know-which-package-is-launching/8878706#8878706

Answer (score 2):

this code will return All packages that have been loaded into the process .

see the results after lauching related apps and make changes .

```
    private String[] AppForground() {

            ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<RunningAppProcessInfo> l = mActivityManager
                    .getRunningAppProcesses();
            Iterator<RunningAppProcessInfo> i = l.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                RunningAppProcessInfo info = i.next();
                if (info.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                    return info.pkgList;
                }
            }

            return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this scenario using following steps. This is my view for solution.

- make setter()/getter() method for activity name.
- whenever you change your activity set that activity's name using set
  method.
- now using getter() method you can see which is currently running
  activity.

Comment: hey Kiran , Please accept the answer if it was useful for you, so that it can be useful for others.

Comment: StackOverflow is not an advertising site. So please stop advertising your answers and let the asker do what he like and choose the answer he found most useful

Comment: seems you did not read question properly . he want which among other app is in foreground (
For example user opens the camera,contacts) .